# Vue is not defined in components

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have file: components.js:

```
import Vue from 'vue'

import SelectCategory from './components/SelectCategoryComponent'
import CommentsManager from './components/CommentsManagerComponent'

Vue.component('select-category', SelectCategory);
Vue.component('comments-manager', CommentsManager);
```

In app.js I imported this file:

```
window.Vue = require('vue');

import './components'
```

But when page is loading I get error: `Vue is not defined`. When I add `import Vue from 'vue'` in every component then all working good. But how I can add Vue globally, without add `import Vue from 'vue'` in every component?

Answer (score 3):

> > But how I can add Vue globally, without add import Vue from 'vue' in every component

You should not use global variables.  Put `import Vue from 'vue'` in every file.

Now, if you still want to, use `global` instead of `window`.  And make sure that file is loaded first.  Or, you might want to set `window=` in your html file, and leave it out of every file.

Comment: Performance will be good, if I import Vue in every component?

Comment: Importing Vue in multiple components doesn't mean you wind up with multiple copies of vue in your build; it just tells webpack what the dependencies are for each component.

Answer (score 2):

As I can see within your `components.js` you have imported `Vue`  and you have imported another `Vue` and you have put it to `window object`. so you have imported 2 different Vue within your application, as well there is no need to use `components.js` and `app.js` that can be confused later. so I suggest you put all your requirement within `app.js` file.
so app.js file will be like this :

```
    import Vue from 'vue'; // es6 syntax
    window.Vue = Vue;

    import SelectCategory from './components/SelectCategoryComponent'
    import CommentsManager from './components/CommentsManagerComponent'

    Vue.component('select-category', SelectCategory);
    Vue.component('comments-manager', CommentsManager);
```